# tqtezos / minter-sdk installation issue

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo

I am trying to run below command for [minter-contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sjDk.png) on my local machine and getting error

```
npm i @tqtezos/minter-contracts
```

no such file or directory, chmod ‘/node_modules/@tqtezos/minter-contracts/env TZ_NETWORK=sandbox ts-node src/bootstrap-contracts-config.ts’

when I run it through yarn it works fine but then yarn compile-ligo doesn’t work.

```
yarn add @tqtezos/minter-contracts
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this. This error was due to a misconfiguration in the package's `package.json` file. I have just published version `@tqtezos/minter-contracts@1.6.1` which should address the issue. Let me know if that solves the problem for you.

Comment: it is not working with yarn or npm. ts-jest@26.1.3 is not compatible with ts version 4.1.5.